# A question about weakly continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow H^1 (\mathbb{R}^3)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

I wonder if the following is true

$$ L_{\mathrm{loc}}^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}_+ ; H^1 (\mathbb{R}^3)) \cap C(\mathbb{R}_+ ; H^{-1} (\mathbb{R}^3)) \subset C_{\mathrm{w}} (\mathbb{R}_+ ; H^1 (\mathbb{R}^3)). \hspace{2cm} (1) $$

For me $\psi \in C_{\mathrm{w}} (\mathbb{R}_+ ; H^1 (\mathbb{R}^3))$ means $\forall L \in H^{-1} (\mathbb{R}^3)$,

$$ \left| \langle \psi (t_n) - \psi (t) , L \rangle_{H^1 , H^{-1}} \right| \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} 0 ~~~~ \mathrm{when} ~~~~ t_n \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} t. $$

I can think I can conclude (1) via the following little argument.

For $L \in H^{-1}$, let $v_L$ denote the $H^1$-function given by the Riesz Representation theorem for $H^1$, i.e.,

$$ L (u) = \langle u , L \rangle_{H^1 , H^{-1}} = \langle u , v_L \rangle_{H^1}. $$

Similarly, for $v \in H^1$ let $L_v$ denote the functional determined by $v$ via the Riesz Representation theorem. Then, since $\psi \in  C (\mathbb{R}_+ ; H^{-1} )$, we have

$$ \left| \langle \psi (t_n) - \psi (t) , L \rangle_{H^1 , H^{-1}} \right| = \left| \langle v_L , L_{\psi (t_n)} - L_{\psi (t)} \rangle_{H^1 , H^{-1}} \right| \leq \| L_{\psi (t_n)} - L_{\psi (t)} \|_{H^{-1}} \| v_L \|_{H^{1}} \rightarrow 0. $$

Is my reasoning correct, or am I misunderstanding the spaces and convergences involved?

Comment: Why should $\|L_{\psi(t_n)}-L_{\psi(t)}\|_{H^{-1}}$ converge to zero? This is equivalent to $\|\psi(t_n)-\psi(t)\|_{H^1}\to0$, which is stronger than what you want to prove.

Comment: I think the claim that $L_{\mathrm{loc}}^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}_+ ; H^1) \cap C(\mathbb{R}_+ ; H^{-1}) \subset C_{\mathrm{w}} (\mathbb{R}_+ ; H^1)$ is true. I found this assertion (without proof) in a paper published in CMP. My argument above maybe wrong, but I believe the claim is correct. Also, what does it mean for $\psi \in C(\mathbb{R}_+ ; H^{-1})$? I thought that if $\psi (t) \in H^1$, then this meant $\| L_{\psi (t_n)} - L_{\psi (t)} \|_{H^{-1}} \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: This is exactly why I am asking the question though. I think I am getting confused with the convergence in the spaces involved. If you could clarify things for me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the claim?

Comment: Yes, "Global finite energy solutions to the Maxwell-Schrodinger equations": https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02099444. The claim is in the paragraph just below equation (4.14).

Comment: @o0BlueBeast0o: When using the Riesz representation theorem, and the $\nu_L$ in your argument, it should rather be $\langle \psi(t_n)-\psi(t),L\rangle_{H^1,H^{-1}} = \langle \psi(t_n)-\psi(t),\nu_L \rangle_{H^1}$, I think... Riesz tells you that there is a representation within $H^1$ -- _in terms of the inner product on $H^1$_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u$ be given as $u\in L^\infty(I, X)$ and $u\in C(\bar I,Y)$ for an intervall $I$, reflexive Banach space $X$ and normed space $Y$ with continuous embedding $X\hookrightarrow Y$. Then $u\in C_w(\bar I,X)$.

Take $t_n\to t$. Then $(u(t_n))$ is bounded in $X$, hence contains a weakly converging subsequence $u(t_{n_k})$ converging weakly to some $\tilde u$ in $X$. Due to the continuity in $Y$, we have $\tilde u= u(t)$. This means the weak subsequential limit does not depend on the subsequence. Moreover, each subsequence of $(u(t_n))$ contains another subsequence converging to $u(t)$ weakly in $X$. This implies $u(t_n)\rightharpoonup u(t)$ in $X$, which is the weak continuity.